# How to associate two entities via REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to associate bidirectional two entities via REST API.
Let's say there is a teacher and class. The Class has an educator that is the teacher and the teacher has the class he is educating.

I've seen other questions about entity associations but didn't work for me.
I've tried @PreUpdate, @PrePersist approach but I was getting null pointer exception... I've also tried sending URL of the resource in 
associated entity place.

Class (without other properties, getters, setters etc.)

```
@Entity
public class Class extends NamedEntity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "educatedClass")
    private Teacher educator;
}
```

Teacher (without other properties, getters, setters etc.)

```
@Entity
public class Teacher extends User {
    @OneToOne
    private Class educatedClass;
}
```

Class controller (without other methods etc.)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "classes")
public class ClassController {
    @PatchMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Class updateClass(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Class class_) {
        return classService.updateClass(id, class_);
    }
}
```

Class service (without other methods, propeteries etc.)

```
@Service
public class ClassServiceImpl implements ClassService{
    @Override
    public Class updateClass(Integer id, Class class_) {
        logger.info(String.format("Update class of ID %d, %s", id, class_));
        Class updatedClass = classRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() ->
                new ResourceNotFoundException("Class not found"));

        updatedClass.update(class_);
        return classRepository.save(updatedClass);
    }
}
```

Class repository

```
@Repository
public interface ClassRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Class, Integer>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Class> {
    Page<Class> findAllBySubjectsId(Integer id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I also have controller, service, repository for the teacher but it looks very similar to the above.

As I mentioned, among others I tried that
[image: Postman request]
But I got

```
JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `blumczynski.com.schoolmanagement.models.Teacher` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/users/teachers/14'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `blumczynski.com.schoolmanagement.models.Teacher`
```

Answer (score 0):

the exception is about constructing the Teacher object . 
you have to put the teacher object in a json format and not a url.

did you try @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) on both of the classes? as explained in this link https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/

if it did not work. please try to make on of the entities allow null for the associated entity. after saving teacher, persist the class and then update the teacher with the class id in a service layer class but in a non transactional method so the id of the class is obtained.
you can achieve this by adding teacher_id and class_id and refer to the class Teacher or Class class as a @Transient one-to-one relation

in my opinion, as a design not, try to remove the class_id from the teacher as the teacher may have multiple classes.